# Is there a way for VBA UDF to "know" what other functions will be run?

Tags: sql, excel, user-defined-functions, excel-2010, vba

Assume I have a UDF that will be used in a worksheet 100,000+ times.  Is there a way, within the function, for it to know how many more times it is going to be called in the batch?  Basically what I want to do is have every function create a to-do list of work to do. I want to do something like:

```
IF remaining functions to be executed after this one = 0 then ...
```

Is there a way to do this?

Background:

I want to make a UDF that will perform SQL queries with the user just giving parameters(date, hour, node, type). This is pretty easy to make if you're willing to actually execute the SQL query every time the function is run. I know its easy because I did this and it was ridiculously slow. My new idea is to have the function first see if the data it is looking for exists in a global cache variable and if it isn't to add it to a global variable "job-list".

What I want it to do is when the last function is called to then go through the job list and perform the fewest number of SQL queries and fill the global cache variable. Once the cache variable is full it would do a table refresh to make all the other functions get called again since on the subsequent call they'll find the data they need in the cache.

Comment: It sounds like this control should be outside of the function anyway. It will be a bad design if functions should know that. How is this information available in the Batch?

Comment: I'm pretty sure a UDF doesn't have access to that kind of information.

Comment: @Bulat, By batch I just meant, the queue of functions to be run like when a user pastes the same function in a bunch of cells.  It seems like the application events that Charles suggested might do the trick just not sure how to implement it for my purpose.  I'll play around with it and see what I learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: 
VBA UDF performance is extremely sensitive to the way the UDF is coded:
see my series of posts about writing efficient VBA UDFs:

http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-3-avoiding-the-vbe-refresh-bug/

http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-1/

You should also consider using an Array UDF to return multiple results:
http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/writing-efiicient-vba-udfs-part5-udf-array-formulas-go-faster/

Secondly:
The 12th post in this series outlines using the AfterCalculate event and a cache
http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/12/05/writing-efficient-udfs-part-12-getting-used-range-fast-using-application-events-and-a-cache/

Basically the approach you would need is for the UDF to check the cache & if not current or available then add a request to the queue.  
 Then use the after-calculation event to process the queue and if neccessary trigger another recalc.

Answer (score 0):

Performing 100,000 SQL queries from an Excel spreadsheet seems like a poor design.  Creating a cache'ing mechanism on top of these seems to compound the problem, making it more complicated than it probably needs to be.  There are some circumstances where this might be appropriate, but I would consider other design approaches instead.

The most obvious is to take the data from the Excel spreadsheet and load it into a table in the database.  Then use the database to do the processing *on all the rows as once*.  The final step is to read the result back into Excel.

I find that the best way to get large numbers of rows from Excel into a database is to save the Excel file as csv and bulk insert them.

This approach may not work for your problem.  In general, though, set-based approaches running in the database are going to perform much better.

As for the cach'ing mechanism, if you have to go down that route.  I can imagine a function that has the following pseudo-code:

```
Check if input values are in cache.
If so, read values from cache.
Else do complex processing.
Load values in cache.
```

This logic could go in the function.  As @Bulat suggests, though, it is probably better to add an additional caching layer around the function.

Comment: I did the approach that required 100,000 SQL queries just to see how bad it performed and it was unacceptably slow, as expected.  Your pseudo code was the most obvious solution for my needs but the problem is the "complex processing" part and it is the core of my question.  My function will do 1 of 3 things, either retrieve data from cache(easy), create/append to a job list(easy), or create the cache from the joblist(doable) but the hard part is making it create cache during the last func call. (ie if user pastes func in 10k cells it should only create the cache once)

Comment: The easy way to do the "Hard Part" is not in the function itself but in the AfterCalculate event